# Amazon Advertising API: report is 'in progress' forever, until 'server is busy'

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

Is anybody else having trouble with Amazon Advertising reports this week or am I doing something wrong?

This was working just fine last week, then all of a sudden I couldn't get reports any more. Instead of requesting a report and it being available max 10 seconds later, I get this response:

`{'reportId': 'snip', 'status': 'IN_PROGRESS', 'statusDetails': 'Report generation is in progress.'}`

Which is nothing out of the ordinary. Then a few minutes later I start getting this:

`{'reportId': 'snip', 'status': 'IN_PROGRESS', 'statusDetails': 'Report generation job has been submitted.'}`

And then eventually:

`{'code': 'SERVER_IS_BUSY', 'details': 'Server is busy. Try again later.', 'requestId': 'snip'}`

Authentication seems to be fine, I think I wouldn't be able to request a report without that working. And I think if I was getting throttled it would tell me that. FYI this is happening in the US and CA stores.

Aside: the Advertising API is such a hard one to google, given that its name is a subset of the Product Advertising API, which is completely different. Hopefully Amazon, given how often they change the names of things, decide to rename this one too.

EDIT: only having this problem with Sponsored Products reports. Sponsored Brands seems to be ok.

Comment: SO is not a “we have a temporary problem” forum. The question and the answer must be relevant for more than a few hours or days. Go to a forum or IRC channel where Amazon API users are present.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the transient status of a third-party service.

Comment: Apologies if this is the wrong sort of question but 1. I'm new here, 2. I didn't know it was about the transient status of a third-party service, I thought I might have been doing something wrong and 3. Stack Overflow is the only place where I've found Amazon Advertising API users present

Comment: I have the same problem: "Server is busy. Try again later." I got your back with an upvote, I don't see why this question is such a big problem if users here can help.

Comment: @KubaOber if somebody comes along and tells me I'm doing something wrong and there's nothing wrong with Amazon it will be hugely helpful

Comment: How do you expect to debug it when you provide only the response? How about the request? Without the request, you don’t show how you do anything, yet you expect to be told what you’re doing wrong. We have no clue since you didn’t consider telling us. Please do, as otherwise this is off-topic. And SO is not a place to answer such problems. Being new is not a problem: there’s [ample documentation about how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO’s job isn’t to be everything for everyone. Amazon API users are here but it’s not a support forum. Ask Amazon support! You pay for it.

Comment: Thanks @KubaOber that's very helpful, I'll add some more details about the request. Sorry to be a noob who hasn't read the rules, I'll go and do that now too.

Answer (score 0):

We use the same API as well, we are getting the same issue and their API has not been stable lately.

Comment: Interestingly, when I get SERVER_IS_BUSY, the HTTP response code is 429 - too many requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning this is an assumption based on my experience with Amazon and
> Cloud Computing

It appears to be that the Amazon Servers are busy,
but searching throughly I could not find any information around this error.

In my case this error went away by itself within a few hours.

When using AWS(Amazon's Cloud Service) I have experienced in the past where the AWS Console was unavailable, yes the entire website, for hours. Usually Cloud Services have a way to stop traffic in the rare case they are overloaded and/or have an issue, to prevent everything from crashing.